# Passing shell variables to system user

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Let's say I want to run some command as system user (no shell):

```
su -s /bin/bash -c "some_command $TEST" my_system_user
```

How di I pass $TEST variable to user?

I have the variable configured for all users in `/etc/profile.d/my_vars.sh`

```
export TEST=test_arg
```

But that doesn't get loaded for the above scenario...

I have tried with no luck:

```
-m (--preserve-environment)
```

Comment: it seems weird, bash should interpolate the variable before executing `su`.

Comment: Use the `env` command? `man env` "env - run a program in a modified environment"

Comment: consider also using `sudo`, which lets you pass environment variables directly within the command line: `sudo TEST="$TEST" ...`

Comment: @Eevee If pass variables in command line directly, then he can simply use `su` as well. I presume that he wants to pass some sensitive data, such as passwords.

Answer (score 3):

First, I tried to create such a file as `/etc/profile.d/my_vars.sh` and I put a test variable in the file. I can see the value of the variable, no matter I run command as whoever. I've also tried to set a variable on-the-fly with the following code, it works on my centos:

```
unset A_VAR; export A_VAR=foo
su -s /bin/bash -c "echo val=$A_VAR" my_system_user
> val=foo
unset A_VAR
```

An alternative solution if it does not work for you, you can consider of playing a `ssh` trick.

```
unset A_VAR; export A_VAR=foo
ssh -o SendEnv my_system_user@localhost "echo val=$A_VAR"
> val=foo
unset A_VAR
```

Answer (score 0):

That's weird. It seems to work for me. I can do:

```
$ export TEST="hello"

$ su -s /bin/bash -c "echo $TEST"
password:
hello
```

...I guess I'm missing something about the question.